# Retrieving data in realtime using Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was trying to retrieve data in realtime with Firebase for my `customInfo` (not real customs, my app is not work for any businesses and just for studying). Such as `Name`, `FamMessage`, `Achievement` `Children`ect.

The Json tree

```
Profile 
0

achievements : [ "Graduated from Harvard University in 1965 with a master in Law."]

children : [ "Jessica", "Jared", "Louise" ]

famMessage : "Love is eternal, love lives on. Sleep til eternity. Time passes, love remains. We remember... with open hearts. A free spirit. Precious are the memories of modest and gentle of heart."

dob: "24/12/1940"

dod: "02/07/2016"

firstname:"Lincon"

lastname:"Hall"

latitude: -34.506081

longitude:150.88104

spouse : "Claudette Hall"

1

achievements : [ "Served in Vietnam before becoming a NAVY Captain", "Aided the Prime Minister in war based decisions for 12 years" ]

famMessage : "Be still. Close your eyes. Breathe. Listen for my football in your heart. I am not gone but merely walk within you."

dob: "05/06/1949"

dod: "08/08/2016"

firstname:"Ben"

lastname:"Roberts"

latitude:-34.50609

longitude:150.8811

spouse : "Elle Roberts"
```

My code:

```
public class Info_window extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView tvName;
public TextView tvDeathRecord;
public TextView tvFamMessage;
public TextView tvSpouse;
public TextView tvChildren;
public TextView tvAchievement;

ChildEventListener mChildEventListner;
DatabaseReference mProfileRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Profile");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_window);

    //Firebase mProfileRef = new Firebase("https://tender-funerals.firebaseio.com/");

    tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvDeathRecord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDeathRecord);
    tvFamMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFamMessage);
    tvSpouse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSpouse);
    tvChildren = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChildren);
    tvAchievement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAchievement);
}

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();


    mChildEventListner = mProfileRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            //String Name = text.getFirstname() + text.getLastname();
            //String DeathRecord = text.getDob() + text.getDod();
            //String FamMessage = text.getFamMessage();
            //String Spouse = text.getSpouse();
            //String Children = text.getChildren();
            //String Achievement = text.getAchievement();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            CustomInfo text = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomInfo.class);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

CustomInfo class

```
public class CustomInfo {
    public String dob;
    public String dod;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String achievement;
    public String children;
    public String famMessage;
    public String spouse;


public CustomInfo(){
}

public CustomInfo(String dob,String dod,String firstname,String lastname, String achievement,String children,String famMessage,String spouse){
    this.dob = dob;
    this.dod = dod;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.achievement = achievement;
    this.children = children;
    this.famMessage = famMessage;
    this.spouse = spouse;
}

public String getDob(){
    return dob;
}

public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}

public String getDod(){
    return dod;
}

public void setDod(String dod) {
    this.dod = dod;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getAchievement(){
    return achievement;
}
public void setAchievement(String achievement){
    this.achievement = achievement;
}

public String getChildren(){
    return children;
}
public void setChildren(String children){
    this.children = children;
}

public String getFamMessage(){
    return famMessage;
}
public void setFamMessage(String famMessage){
    this.famMessage = famMessage;
}

public String getSpouse(){
    return spouse;
}
public void setSpouse(String spouse){
    this.spouse = spouse;
}
}
```

Now how would I retrieve data and also if the custom who doesn't have any childs, how to slove it when retrieving data ?

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to retrieve the data from onChildAdded function, onChildChanged function will be called at the time of change in data.

```
mChildEventListner = mProfileRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            CustomInfo text = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomInfo.class);
            //String Name = text.getFirstname() + text.getLastname();
            //String DeathRecord = text.getDob() + text.getDod();
            //String FamMessage = text.getFamMessage();
            //String Spouse = text.getSpouse();
            //String Children = text.getChildren();
            //String Achievement = text.getAchievement();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {



        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, it should be in onChildAdded. Thanks for that :)

Comment: actually, it doesn't works for my app. Thanks again for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this..

```
DatabaseReference mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

//Create List to store data
List<YourModel> mMyDataList = new ArrayList<>();

mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //clear before adding data to list
            mMyDataList.clear();                

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.child("Profile").getChildren()) {
                YourModel mModel = postSnapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);
                mMyDataList.add(mModel); // add data to list 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            toastMsg(databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Use list to show your data..